# except on elseif statements use PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple script like this:

```
if($data == "ok") {
    echo "OKAY";
} elseif ($data *I DONT KNOW*) {
    echo "NOT OKAY";
}
```

I want an exception for the elseif part, for example, `$data` is not "OK", it will generate "NOT OKAY"

Is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand, you want it to `echo` out your `NOT OKAY`, you realise you are missing your comparison operators, right? Could you clarify, please.

Comment: `$data != "ok"` or just use else instead of elseif

Comment: just else mate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($data == "ok") {
    echo "OKAY";
} elseif ($data != "ok") {
    echo "NOT OKAY";
}
```

or even easier

```
if($data == "ok") {
    echo "OKAY";
} else {
    echo "NOT OKAY";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($data == "ok") {
    echo "OKAY";
} else {
    echo "NOT OKAY";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Exception, then just throw one like this:

```
if ($data == 'ok') {
    echo "OKAY";
} elseif ($data == 'nok') {
   throw new Exception('NOT OKAY');
}
```

Then you can catch the exeption with something like this:

```
function checkData(string $data) {
    if ($data == 'ok') {
        echo "OKAY";
    } elseif ($data == 'nok') {
       throw new Exception('NOT OKAY');
    }
}

try {
   checkData($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   //my exception handling.
   echo $e->getMessage(); // will output "NOT OKAY"
}
```

This can be in any other part of code of course.